# Resize / position div after orientationchange event

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html, mobile-safari

I have written some simple code that listens for the 'orientationchange' (Safari/iOS) event and then attempts to resize a div to the new window orientation/size.

The problem is that the resizing and positioning is not working in the way I'm expecting. I'm wanting the div to resize (with gradient background) and fill the screen. I've attached screen grabs to highlight the problem.

I'd be massively grateful if anyone can show me why my code is not working.

My testing is using Apple's iPhone Simulator, opening Safari (on Simulator) and pointing it to my localhost where the following test code resides:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Div Resizing/positioning Test</title>

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .masterTemplate {
        position: absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient( -70deg, black 60%, navy );
        border: 1px solid magenta;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="masterTemplate"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() { 

        console.log("document ready");

        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", onOrientationChange );

        $("#masterTemplate").css( { width:window.innerWidth, height:window.innerHeight } );
        $("#masterTemplate").addClass("masterTemplate");

        function onOrientationChange(event) {
            console.log('onOrientationChange',event);
            $("#masterTemplate").removeClass("masterTemplate");
            $("#masterTemplate").css({ width:window.innerWidth, height:window.innerHeight, top:"0px", left:"0px" });
            $("#masterTemplate").addClass("masterTemplate");
        }

     } );

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: This is correct][image: div seems to have partially slipped off screen][image: Incorrect position and size]

Comment: How about `.masterTemplate {height:100%;width:100%}` ?

Comment: ...thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestion and it makes no difference. The position is not correct on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem right... -> width:window.innerWidth, height:window.innerHeight. If all you want is to give the div the window width and height why not set it through css?

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: ...thanks for your reply. I have tried this and it still doesn't work. The positioning of the div is the same as the screen grabs shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize the window by changing the JavaScript code with something like:

Instead 
`$("#masterTemplate").css( { width:window.innerWidth, height:window.innerHeight } );`

use 
   `var clientWidth = jQuery(window).width();
   var clientHeight = jQuery(window).height();
   window.resizeTo( clientWidth,clientHeight )`,

where `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` are width and height in pixels.

Or, if you prefer using your jQuery selector, try with:

`$("#masterTemplate").css( { width:jQuery(window).width(), height:jQuery(window).height() } );`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I've also tried this too and there's no difference. My gut feeling is that it's quite specific to mobile quirks...sadly my Javascript/HTML5 for mobile is still in its infancy...

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head on a brick wall for a couple hours, I seem to have found the answer to my own question and would like to post it as it may help others that are in their early days of HTML5 mobile development.

There are occasions when whatever you're planning may involve manually controlling the Viewport. If you're not sure what the Viewport is, there are many very good articles and examples of configuration, one being [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOs/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)!

My problem stemmed from being unaware that I needed to reset(hopefully the right term) the viewport after each rotation of the device. Adding the following code into the 'orientationchange' event handler resolved my problem:

```
var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0')
```

I also trimmed the initial viewport meta config to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```